# Is It Possible To Lock/Freeze Windows 10 Taskbar Icons?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

Often I must drag icons from the unseen/unused portion/s of the taskbar to the part of the taskbar I can see. For example, I must endlessly drag the Chrome icon from the "bottom" of the taskbar, the unseen part, to the "top," in order to be able to make the icon more quickly available to my mouse pointer (that is, when the Chrome/application icon is at the "top" of the taskbar, one isn't required to scroll down however many "layers" to the "bottom" of the taskbar just to be able to select it with the mouse pointer).

So, then, I am simply wondering if there is any way to lock all icons in place so as to undermine this persistent, irritating necessity. Thank you!

Comment: Could you add a screenshot? I'm not too clear by what you mean by top and bottom of the taskbar.

Comment: You can pin the icon.  This has an added advantage that you can 1) start the program from this icon when it's not running, 2) bring the running window forward if already running, and 3) Start another copy of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the icon in the taskbar and select "Pin to taskbar". This will maintain the place of the icon in the taskbar as long there are no apps between which are not pinned, but if the focus is on an app which has is icon in the scrolled part you will have to scroll, alternatively you can use `Win` + `1` to `0` key combination to activate the first 10 icons in the taskbar, so if you pin 10 most used apps on your taskbar you will have a quick option to run/activate the app. A second option would be to resize the taskbar so it shows all icons and use the Auto Hide Feature of the Taskbar so you have the screen available.